# MongoDB pushing objects to array within object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, router, patch

I am trying to push a new object to an array with objects inside another object (see DB Schema here: [MongoDB set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaBDq.png)). Trying to push to notes within subtopics[2] object within the topic.

This is the code but it ends up deleting the specified subtopic id:

```
router.patch('/:topicId/:subtopicId/note', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const subtopicNote = await Note.update(
            {_id: req.params.topicId},
            {subtopics : 
                    { _id: req.params.subtopicId, 
                        $push: {
                        notes: 
                            {note: req.body.note}       
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        res.json(subtopicNote);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ messsage: err})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :)

```
router.patch('/:topicId/:subtopicId/note', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const subtopicNote = await Note.updateOne(
            {_id: req.params.topicId,  subtopics : {"$elemMatch": {"_id":req.params.subtopicId}}},
            { $push : {
                'subtopics.$.notes': {note: req.body.note}
            }
            }
        )

        res.json(subtopicNote);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err})
    }
})
```